# How can I insert a svg containing links in a xwiki page?

Tags: svg, xwiki

Context :

I have a svg graphics containing links to external pages. If I open it directly in Firefox or IE links correctly go to the other URLs.

I want to insert the graphics in a xWiki page. The trivial way : `Image/Attached image...` in wisiwig editor generates `[[image:foo.svg||height="..." width="..."]]` in xwiki 2.1 source but ... links are no longer clickable.

Question :

How can I insert the svg document in a way links in the svg are still active ?

Minimal example :

```html
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <rect x="0" y="0" height="130" width="120"
          style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
    <rect x="10" y="10" height="50" width="100"
          style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
    <a xlink:href="http://www.google.fr">
 <rect x="10" y="70" height="50" width="100"
       style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #00ff00"/>
    </a>
</svg>
```

As you can see the green rectangle at bottom contains a link to google. But when I insert it in a xwiki page, the link is not active. I looked at generated HTML, and saw that the svg is included with an `<img>` tag and I assume it is the reason why links are not active. But I could not find how to make it work

References :

I'm using a 6.4.4 version of xwiki and 2.1 xwiki syntax but I will accept a solution for version 7 or another syntax for xwiki pages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is not with XWiki, but with the way browsers handle SVGs as the target of `<img>` tags. You can try in a simple HTML:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <image src="foo.svg"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

That won't be clickable either.

You can embed the SVG instead:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
      <rect x="0" y="0" height="130" width="120"
          style="stroke:#000000; fill: #ffffff"/>
      <rect x="10" y="10" height="50" width="100"
          style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #0000ff"/>
      <a xlink:href="http://www.google.fr">
        <rect x="10" y="70" height="50" width="100"
              style="stroke:#ff0000; fill: #00ff00"/>
      </a>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

If you can copy the contents of the SVG file in the wiki document, then you can just use a `{{html clean="false"}}` wrapper around it:

```
Some **wiki content**

{{html clean="false"}}
<svg ....>
</svg>
{{/html}}

Some __other wiki content__.
```

If not, then you should do this instead:

```
Some **wiki content**

{{velocity}}
{{html clean="false"}}
$doc.getAttachment('foo.svg').getContentAsString('UTF-8')
{{/html}}
{{/velocity}}

Some __other wiki content__.
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But direct inclusion of a `<svg>` bloc in a HTML page does not work in IE. Fortunately, it is easy to use an `<object>` tag : `{{velocity}}{{html}}<object data="$doc.getAttachmentURL('foo.svg')" type="image/svg+xml" width="120" height="320"/>{{/html}}{{/velocity}}`. This one worked on Firefox, Chrome and IE